# How to make class inner ul li css

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

The following css style be like this:

```
ul {         
    padding:0 0 0 0;
    margin:0 0 0 0;
}
#foo li {     
   list-style:none;
   margin-bottom:25px;           
}
ul li img {
   cursor: pointer;
}
```

The ul li has included:

```
<ul id="foo" class="row">
  <li class="col-lg-3 col-md-3 ">
  <img class="img-responsive" src="images/photodune-174908-rocking-the-night-away-xs.jpg">
  </li>
</ul>
```

Is it possible to change #ul from id into class ? I tried be like this:

```
ul {         
  padding:0 0 0 0;
  margin:0 0 0 0;
}
li.bar {     
  list-style:none;
  margin-bottom:25px;           
}
ul li img {
  cursor: pointer;
}

<ul id="" class="row bar">
  <li class="col-lg-3 col-md-3 ">
    <img class="img-responsive" src="images/photodune-174908-rocking-the-night-away-xs.jpg">
  </li>
</ul>
```

It works but there's something wrong that I think it's not working as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since your `li` tag doesn't have the `.bar` class it can't work.

If you want to style the `li` change the css to:

```
.bar li {
    list-style:none;
    margin-bottom:25px; 
}
```

**or**

if you want to style the `ul` change the css to:

```
ul.bar {
    list-style:none;
    margin-bottom:25px;
}
```

With your css code you style a `li` tag with the `.bar` class.

Comment: Thank you sir, you've answered my question. I've used .bar li {} :)

Answer (score 0):

Try this instead

```
ul.bar li{     
    list-style:none;
    margin-bottom:25px;           
}
```

Or this

```
.bar li{     
    list-style:none;
    margin-bottom:25px;           
}
```

Comment: Sorry, both of those codes have changed my default bootstrap style. Here's reference http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43091109/how-to-make-css-for-class-in-single-page, they were answered to change just only ul id not the other style.